# Can a job title or position be used without an article?

Tags: expressions, bare-role-noun-phrases

Can someone's position in their workplace be used without an article in a subject complement (as if it were an adjective)  and
will there be no difference in meaning from when it was used with an article.

For example:

> My uncle was head copy editor of the NY Times.

This is excerpted from a random website thread.

To me, "a head copy editor" sounds more natural (as follows):

> My uncle was **a** head copy editor of the NY Times.

I understand a position or individual's social status can be used like "He is president of the United States."

I learned when it is used without an article, the sentence focuses more on the nature of the mentioned position than when it is used with one.

Comment: "Adjective" isn't the right word. These are nouns without an article. "object" may be confusing as there is a grammatical term "object". I shall try to edit.

Answer (score 2):

If there are more than one editor with the title of "head copy editor" then you can definitely use the indefinite article. Nevertheless, if there is only one person with the title "head copy editor" then use the definite article or no article at all.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the confusion arises because even though there is only one head copy editor, & for that matter only one president, there have been many over the years.

So...

> "My uncle was head copy editor of the NY Times."

Signifies he was the only one **at that time**.

> "My uncle was a head copy editor of the NY Times."

implies that there was a series of them over the years & that he was merely one of that series.

I would only use this form if it was to emphasise he was one of many, not that he achieved that proud position, being the only one in his time.

If he had been a junior copy editor, one of several at any time, then

> "My uncle was a copy editor at the NY Times."

[I only just realised 'of' doesn't work so well in that construction, which makes me now question whether it ought to also be 'at' in the first examples too.]

Similarly...

> "He is president of the United States."

Again, there is only one at a time.

As president is rather a singular position anyway, it even sounds a little odd to say

> "John Quincy Adams was **a** president of the USA"

even though he was one of many. You would be more likely to say

> "John Quincy Adams was president of the USA"

again, though he was one of many, he was the only one at that time.